# Can anyone help me with this one?

Tags: riddle

> I am born  as one colour and change to another before I reach the last colour. What am I?

Can anybody help? It would probably be Harry Potter or magic related.

Comment: Any sort of plant that ripens (then rots) would fit this, among other things.

Comment: The answer might be the color of a person's hair (or eyes) which can change over time.

Answer (score 4):

It could certainly be

> traffic lights,

but the question sounds as though it might be "too broad".